# Find 2 highest values in an object - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the top 2 highest values from an object:

```
emotions = {
      joy: 52,
      surprise: 22,
      contempt: 0,
      sadness: 98,
      fear: 60,
      disgust: 20,
      anger: 1,
  };
```

I understand I can do `Math.max()` with all these values, but it will return just the value of sadness in this example. Can I somehow get top 2, with label (sadness) and value (98)?

Comment: Just sort them and take the first 2 elements?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value see this for hint

Comment: What is your required output format? `[{sadness:98},{fear:60}]` or `[{fear:60},{sadness:98}]` or `{fear:60, sadness:98}` (in the last case it will be in no particular order, of course)

Comment: @JaromandaX It would be ideal to get both label and value, since I need to write out as text, 1st one then 2nd one

Comment: right ... but **what actual format do you want the actual output to be** all three I suggested have label and value - perhaps `[["fear", 60],["sadness", 98]]` or `[["sadness", 98],["fear", 60]]` - these also have both label and value

Comment: @JaromandaX the first one would work [{sadness:98},{fear:60}]

Comment: They all work, it depends on what you want :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the entries, sort them and return objects which are converted to a single one.

```js
var emotions = { joy: 52, surprise: 22, contempt: 0, sadness: 98, fear: 60, disgust: 20, anger: 1 },
    top2 = Object
        .entries(emotions)
        .sort(({ 1: a }, { 1: b }) => b - a)
        .slice(0, 2)
        .map(([label, value]) => ({ label, value }));
  
 console.log(top2);
```

Comment: Hm, it works in your example, but I get an error: Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0 or more. it shows the error for line top 2 = ... Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: which user agent (browser) do you use?

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: i changed the output. it should work with it. where do you get the error?

Comment: It helps to know the expected output :p